# Standard Engine modes

Tags: informix

INFORMIX-SE (multi-user versions):

Can I start SE in maintenance (standalone mode) where the DBA is the only user who can access the engine, then change its mode so that all users can access it?

(This is analogous to booting Unix in single-user mode and then going multi-user. Oracle provides this functionality.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no modes in Informix Standard Engine (SE) analogous to those in Informix Dynamic Server (IDS).

You can connect to an SE database with:

```
DATABASE dbname EXCLUSIVE;
```

This will fail if anyone is using the database; it will prohibit anyone else from connecting to the database until the session is over - at which point anyone can connect again.